# How can i prevent scaling object in three,js on window resize?

Tags: jquery, three.js, perspectivecamera

I want to prevent object to scaling on window resize. I can't find value which is changing when i resize window. More intresting that, object resizes only then I resize window VERTICALY.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2r7J.jpg <-- full screen

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqbIE.jpg <-- prevent object resize on window resize

So my main question is:
What is the value which is changing when I resize window.

Comment: This has not so much to do with `three.js` but with how you define your HTML5 canvas element. Maybe you should just set your canvas element to a fixed size?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, the cameras field of view needs to be updated when the window size changes. Here is a [working example / fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4Jpu/165/) on how to achieve it, below is the snippet that calculates the new FOV. The [original github issue.](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1406)

```
// remember these initial values
var tanFOV = Math.tan( ( ( Math.PI / 180 ) * camera.fov / 2 ) );
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

$(window).on('resize', function ()
{
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.fov = (360 / Math.PI) * Math.atan(tanFOV * (window.innerHeight / windowHeight));
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
```

Comment: What is "tanFOV", and "windowHeight" in this solution?